# which life cycle function should i call after going out of my app and come back

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, application-lifecycle

i have an app that allows the users to make a phone call, when the user click on a button on my app, i open the phone app, then the user may or may not call. in any cases, the user will (should) come back to my app, in that case, i want to do some processing. i would like to know which function suites my need the best.

as i read in other ansewrs, sounds like i have to:

1. Save an indicator when the user open my app using the view did load function
2. on the view will appear, i check if the user alrady saved that indicator, that means this is not the first time he visit this page and he has (should have) alreayd opened the phone app

**but i am not sure**

i need your help to prove my think

thanks

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate methods are of course the reasonable choice, but with the methods, I would suggest using:

- `applicationWillResignActive()` as the method before you enter from your app to multitasking window OR to the background. `applicationWillEnterForeground()` will only fire up when you will hit the background, but won't take the multitasking fraction with you.
- `applicationDidBecomeActive()` as the method when you come back from
  multitasking OR background. Same reason as before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use application lifecycle functions from your AppDelegate to notify your controllers instead relying directly on view controller lifecycle.

Appropriate methods:

`applicationDidEnterBackground:` - called just after your app goes to the background 
`applicationWillEnterForeground:` - called just before it will go foreground again (it will be called on app launch too so this is a place which you should double check!)